# How can I record changes made during in-place editing in Perl?

Tags: perl, file, replace, find, logging

I've scripted up a simple ksh that calls a Perl program to find and replace in files.
The passed-in arg is the home directory:

```
 perl -pi -e 's/find/replace/g' $1/*.html
```

It works great.  However, I'd like to output all the changes to a log file.  I've tried piping and redirecting and haven't been able to get it work.  Any ideas?

Thanks,
Glenn

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by 'the changes'?  What is it that should appear in the log file?

Comment: I'm thinking the filename along with the entire line(s) containing the find string before the replace.  Unless you have any better suggestions.  Perhaps just the filename with line number changed would suffice.

Comment: Both answers work similarly.  I picked the one that was answered first.  Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like this to send all changes to STDERR:

```
perl -pi -e '$old = $_; s/find/replace/g and warn "${ARGV}[$.]: $old $_"; close ARGV if eof' $1/*.html
```

Updated: Fixed $. on multiple files.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it tonight.  Just wondering if you can explain the variables?  denkfaul's solutions redirects the output to logfile.txt.  In your solution I'm not sure which variable is pointing to the logfile.  And I'll pose the same question to you that I did to denkfaul regarding using Perl...

Comment: "warn" outputs to STDERR, so you can redirect it to a log file just like in denkfaul's answer. "$ARGV" is the name of the current file, "ARGV" is the filehandle, $_ is the current line, $. is the current line number. See "perldoc perlvar" and "perldoc -f eof"

Comment: Excellent.  Thanks.  And did you get a chance to see the question I was referring to in the second part: 'Would the solution be easier or be more logical if I switched to a native Perl script from a ksh script'?

Answer (score 3):

You can print to STDERR and redirect just the STDERR output to a file as below:

```
perl -pi -e 'chomp($prev=$_);s/find/replace/g and print STDERR "$ARGV - $.: $prev -> $_"; close ARGV if eof' $1/*.html 2> logfile.txt
```

*edit: added the filename, and fixed line number display when multiple input files are used*

Comment: Honestly, I thought of the eof thing, came back here to make an edit, and noticed that you already changed yours :-)

Comment: no worries :)
I would've added comments to yours initially, rather than create a similar answer, but I don't yet have the rep :|

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try tonight.
Would the solution be easier or be more logical if I switched to a native Perl script from a ksh script?

Comment: @glenwark: For something this simple, it doesn't matter much which way you do it.